# Substituir input file por ícone/imagem com Preview de Imagem

Tags: html, css

Tenho um `form` aonde possui um  `input file` com `preview` de imagem antes do upload, to tentando substituir o `input` por uma imagem, mas não estou conseguindo.

**SCRIPT PREVIEW**
[image: Como está ficando!!!]

```
<script>
    // PREVIEW FOTO
    function PreviewImage() {
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
        };
    };
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="image-upload"><label for="file-input">
                                        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/54/38/19/543819d33dfcfe997f6c92171179e4cd.png" id="uploadPreview" style="width: 110px; height: 110px;" />  
                                        <input id="uploadImage" id="file-input" type="file" name="foto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
```

**CSS**

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .image-upload > input
    {
    display: none;
    }
    </style>
```

**Alguém me ajuda, agradeço desde já.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, a sua tag `div` não foi fechada corretamente, por isso o css aplicado na classe `image-upload` não foi aplicado e o botão de selecionar arquivo continuava em evidência.

Segundo, o atributo `for` da tag `label` precisa ter o mesmo valor que o atributo `id` da sua tag `input`. No seu código, a tag `input` possuia dois atributos `id`.

Alterando o seu HTML para o exemplo abaixo, funcionará corretamente.

```
<div class="image-upload">
        <label for="uploadImage">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/54/38/19/543819d33dfcfe997f6c92171179e4cd.png" id="uploadPreview" style="width: 110px; height: 110px;">
        </label>  
        <input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="foto" onchange="PreviewImage();">
    </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou! uma perguntinha, não tem como ficar o quadradinho do lado aonde aparecia a imagem então?

Comment: Sim, remova o CSS .image-upload > input { display: none;} e então o botão de Selecionar Imagem ficará ao lado da imagem de preview.